# Issues with Go Project structure

Tags: go

I have a project where I want to build multiple binaries accessing the same logic (from the same package).

My folder structure looks like this

```
.
├── app
│   ├── bin_a
│   │   └── bin_a.go
│   ├── bin_b
│   │   └── bin_b.go
├── pkg
│   ├── model.go
└── go.mod
```

go.mod

```
module github.com/user/module
go 1.19
```

bin_a.go

```golang
package main

import("github.com/user/module/pkg/model")

func main() {
    user := User{}
}
```

model.go

```golang
package main

type User struct { }
```

If I try to build `bin_a` e.g. `go build app/bin_a/bin_a.go` I get the following error message

```
no required module provides package github.com/user/module/pkg/model; to add it:
        go get github.com/user/module/pkg/model
package command-line-arguments: cannot find package
```

This is weird since its the same package!
I also made sure that there is a symlink from within my gopath e.g.
`/home/user/go/github.com/user/module/app/` to my repository

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't have pkg/model package.
In the bin_a/bin_a.go file you named your package correctly, but my opinion you should name you file main.go under the bin_a/ and bin_b/ folders. Still those are the main entry points.

Secondly, the folder name should be the package name. You should create a model/ folder under the pkg/ and set the package name in the model.go to `package model` or when you leave this under the pkg/ folder, then use `package pkg`.

In the bin_a/bin_a.go you should use the following import path:
`import "github.com/user/module/pkg"` or with my suggestion `import "github.com/user/module/pkg/model"`

So the folder structure will be:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── bin_a
│   │   └── main.go
│   ├── bin_b
│   │   └── main.go
├── pkg
│   ├── model
│   │   └── user.go
└── go.mod
```

And the codes:

```golang
/////////////////////////////////
// bin_a/main.go

package main

import("github.com/user/module/pkg/model")

func main() {
    user := User{}
}

//////////////////////////////////////////
// model.go
package model

type User struct { }
```

You should check these docs:

- https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout
- https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules